# WinUI3 Standalone Executible produces many additional files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, winui-3

Background: I am switching from WinForm to WinUi3 and we have the need to deliver the application as a usually windows executable. Therefore the idea was to deliver it as a standalone exe program.

I have selected self hosted in the project and also the single file option. after publish I get a large collection of files in the folder.
The dll files can still be accepted, but many language folders are superfluous, especially the program is monolingual.

Is there a possibility to get it under control or are there other possibilities?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most properties here are related to .NET wich ~kinda supports single file deployment. However, WinUI3 (in the WinAppSDK vehicle) is an extra layer. When WinAppSDK is "self-contained" then, there's no support for single file. Will this be possible out-of-the-box in the future? Not sure about the roadmap which is currently very fuzzy. PS: you can delete the language directories you don't use... better than nothing. You can also trim the .exe a bit more with PublishTrimmed=true and/or PublishReadyToRun=true and/or IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true (but needs testing as not always working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove unnecessary language folders, except your default language folder (en-us in this case), by adding these lines in your csproj file.

```xml
<Project...>


  <Target Name="RemoveFoldersWithMuiFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RemovingFiles Include="$(OutDir)*\*.mui" Exclude="$(OutDir)en-us\*.mui" />
      <RemovingFolders Include="@(RemovingFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(RemovingFolders)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```